# How to draw a regular lattice in R?

Tags: r, igraph, mathematical-lattices

I'm new to R and want to construct a regular lattice with 30 nodes and k=4 (neighborhood connectivity).

I've tried the igraph package with graph.lattice function, but cannot produce what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A regular lattice in iGraph with k = 4 neighbourhood connectivity:

```
require(igraph)
g <- graph.lattice( c(5,6) )
g <- connect.neighborhood(g, 4)
plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I look for something like this: 'd=graph.lattice(30,nei=2,directed=FALSE, circular=TRUE)'

Comment: @Issac have you answered your own question, or is there something else you are looking for?

Comment: @Issac I wonder if you could be more specific about *cannot produce what I'm looking for*?

Comment: @Gary No, I wanted to add some hints about what I was trying to get in R.

Comment: @SimonO101 Thanks! This is what I was chasing. Sorry for not being to the point in the first post.

Comment: @Issac You are welcome! If it answered your question satisfactorily please could you press then green tick next to my answer so this question can be taken off the unanswered questions stack. Many thanks! Welcome to SO btw.